# Динамическая подгрузка контента onScroll

Tags: java, android, listview

Я новичок в java, подскажите что я делаю не так.
Проблема заключается в том что мне нужно по мере скролинга добавлять все новый и новый контент. В моем коде где то ошибка, или я не правильно понимаю логику некоторых функций, объясните в чем дело и как это поправить.

Мой MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String debug = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.items);
        new ContentAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, items, 0).execute();


        items.setOnScrollListener(new InfiniteScrollListener(5) {
            @Override
            public void loadMore(int currentPage, int totalItemsCount) {

                new ContentAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, items, totalItemsCount).execute();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Класс ContentAsyncTask.java Получаем контент по URL и добавляет его

```
class ContentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, List<Document>> {

    private String debug = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private View view;
    private int skip;

    ContentAsyncTask(Context context, View view, int skip) {
        this.context = context;
        this.view = view;
        this.skip = skip;
    }


    @Override
    protected List<Document> doInBackground(Object... params) {

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        String page = "https://site.ru/getContent?limit=20&skip=" + this.skip;

        JSONArray content = sh.makeServiceCall(page);

        List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {

            try {

                JSONObject x = content.getJSONObject(i);

                Document document = gson.fromJson(x.toString(), Document.class);

                //list.add(document);
                list.add(new Document(i, document.getImage("mid"), document.getDomain()));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Document> documents) {
        super.onPostExecute(documents);

        ProductListAdapter adapter = new ProductListAdapter(context.getApplicationContext(), documents);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.items);

        if(this.skip == 0 ) {

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else {

            adapter.addListItemToAdapter(documents);

        }
    }
}
```

InfiniteScrollListener.java

```
abstract class InfiniteScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private int bufferItemCount = 10;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int itemCount = 0;
    private boolean isLoading = true;

    InfiniteScrollListener(int bufferItemCount) {
        this.bufferItemCount = bufferItemCount;
    }

    abstract void loadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        // Do Nothing2
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (totalItemCount < itemCount) {
            this.itemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.isLoading = true; }
        }

        if (isLoading && (totalItemCount > itemCount)) {
            isLoading = false;
            itemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        if (!isLoading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + bufferItemCount)) {
            loadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
            isLoading = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно вопрос подгрузки списка решается иначе. В адаптере списка есть метод `getView()`. Этот метод вызывается, когда отрисовывается очередной элемент списка. В этом методе есть параметр `int position`, который дает нам порядковый номер показываемого элемента. Очень легко проверить, является ли `position` концом списка (или почти концом), если да, то грузим данные.

Слушать события `onScroll` плохая идея, так как они срабатывают очень часто при малейшем скроле списка.

Comment: Да надо будет переделать, но все же можете пояснить почему не работает мой код? Вроде бы и в функцию ProductListAdapter.addListItemToAdapter() данные приходят, а вот document.addAll(list); не добавляет ничего.

Comment: Нужно дебагером смотреть. У Вас очень много меняющихся состояний, визуально по коду сложно понять, что происходит в моменты скролла.

Comment: В дебагере очень много информации различной, у меня глаза разбегаются =) На что обратить внимание, может есть какие то определенные  события?

Comment: Эмм, погуглить как пользоваться дебагером, ставить брекпоинты и отлаживать пошагово программу. Это мастхэв для разработчика.